# Attempt to read property "url" on null in php api

Tags: php

I have following php api to fetch some third party json data.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://players-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/players?number=1'; // path to your JSON file
$imgUrl='https://random.cricket/players.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$dataImg= file_get_contents($imgUrl);
$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
$imgCharacters = json_decode($dataImg, true);

echo $characters[0]->fact;
echo $imgCharacters[0]->url;
print_r($imgCharacters);

?>
```

Here, when I run this php file, it gives me the correct output for

```
echo $characters[0]->fact;
```

But it kept giving me an error for the

```
echo $imgCharacters[0]->url;
```

The error is,

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "url" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cricinfo\player-fact-app\index.php on line 11
```

When I print the second array, it giving me something like follows,

```
Array ( [fileSizeBytes] => 285621 [url] => https://random.players/a62ccc75-2b8b-48d1-9110-b6e8d5687c07.jpg )
```

Comment: `$imgCharacters` is an associative array, not indexed. You want `$imgCharacters['url']`

Comment: Well your are decoding the json as array and not as an object, . So ``$imgCharacters[0]['url'];``. Or just remove the "true" from the json_decode  to not decode it as array.

Comment: You use json_decode($dataImg, true); -> true => array. Remove true to have an object. Or do $imgCharacters[0]['url']; (but, I'm not sure you have an index 0 =>  $imgCharacters['url'];)

Answer (score 1):

You parsed the second array as an associative array. There is no index 0, you can access the url using the key $imgCharacters['url']. (without -> as it is not an object)